# D3js skips data

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have this CSV file (with 4 rows and 6 columns of data). While parsing the values:

```
      var headers = d3.keys(data[0])
        .filter(function(key) { return key !== ""; });
      for(i=0;i<headers.length;i++)
        data.forEach(function (d){
          d[headers[i]] = +d[headers[i]];
      })
      data.forEach(function (d){
        console.log(d[headers[4]]);
      })
```

But once I used the console log command to check the data for every column I realised that some data are missing. I noticed that if the values are the same(two 5 for example) somehow they one is skipped. How  can I change that? Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide a complete example please?

Comment: That doesn't look like CSV data.

Comment: Ye sorry I made a mistake here. Ok I have this table which is in excel normaly. http://pareto.xylakis.net63.net/. (Im exporting it as csv). As you notice there are more than one columns thats why I use  for to go through all the columns and parse all the data to int. My problem though is that in cases that the values are the same(the previous with the next value, check the two last columns where Ι have the zeroes) it takes only the first value(the first zero) and leaves the rest. So lets say that I want to print the last column(5Goals) I get the result [1 0] intstead of getting [1 0 0 0]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data with which the problem occurs?

Comment: A sample of the data? Thats the data that Im using. In the table that I have posted above. Link :  pareto.xylakis.net63.net . The problem occurs when the sequential values are the same.

Comment: The page above contains only a static table. I'm asking for a sample of the data and a full example so that I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is the problem that you're not seeing the duplication in console.log? In Chrome, repeatedly logging the same value to the console doesn't display an additional line; it puts a counter of the number of repeated values to the left. So you would expect to see "1" on one line and then "(3) 0" on the next line.

Comment: Exxalty angus l! It doesnt actually skip data but it just doesnt appear on the console.log. I found about that today.. Thnx for all the help though